# SugarCRM Studio > Profit Calculator > Fields Warning Message

Tags: php, sugarcrm

when adding a new field this warning appears

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\SugarCE-Full-6.5.16\modules\ModuleBuilder\views\view.modulefield.php on line 321

{"east":{"title":"Edit Field","crumb":"","content":"
</div>\n\n

what can i do to solve it

```
foreach ( $module->mbvardefs->vardefs['fields'] as $field )
    {
        if ($field [ 'type' ] == 'enum' || $field [ 'type'] == 'multienum' )
        {
            $triggers [] = $field [ 'name' ] ;
        }

        if (!isset($field['source']) || $field['source'] != 'non-db') {
            if(preg_match('/^(.*?)(_c)?$/', $field['name'], $matches))
            {
                $existing_field_names [] = strtoupper($matches[1]); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us code from modulefield.php (line 321 and some earlier)

Comment: Before foreach you should use var_dump($module->mbvardefs->vardefs['fields']) to check if it's array. It should be when you use foreach. Now it seems it is something else.

Comment: var_dump of array is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before and from what I can tell, it's a bug where Studio doesn't like some of the fields in your system. Probably the fields were created with an older version of SugarCRM or brought in by a less-than-stellar third party plugin. Either way, this goes away if you change your php settings to `display_errors=Off`.

Further, to be pedantic about what you're seeing... The page is expecting an AJAX response from the system. The response should be JSON or whatever, but attached to the response is a PHP Warning or Notification. This throws off the format and content of the output, so the JavaScript on the page can't process it correctly.

If you want to find the upstream source of the issue, go to /custom/modules/MyModule/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.php and look for whatever's missing. Replace "MyModule" with the name of the module you're editing when you get this message.

Answer (score 0):

It simple mean that you created field without value. You should somewhere in your code run something like that:

```
$module->mbvardefs->vardefs['fields'][] = array ('type' => 'enum', 'name' => 'blabla');
```

to use this variable in foreach in this foreach loop. But I'm not sugarcrm system so it's only a hint